# What may be said about someone who is a certain type of person, and who only seems to be so?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idioms

**Edited:**

Quite often, some people are ready to do anything to make an impression of being a certain type of a person that they actually are not.

For example, being asked for her first impression about Mr X, Mrs Z may say:

> "He is a  gentleman… (?)*"

*Here, I'm looking for a word or phrase which may express the idea that Mr X gives Mrs Z the impression of  what she thinks  an entirely, in all ways a perfect type of a gentleman must be. What I've been able to come up with so far is "from top to toe"/"through and through", which doesn't seem to match the usage standards in this context.

Some time later, Mrs Z may find out that Mr X, say, has the habit of biting his nails, or that wears the same pair of socks for several days, or something like that. So he wasn't what she had taken him for at the first glimpse.

In this regard, I'm searching for idioms or colloquial phrases for  Mrs Z to  explain why she took Mr X for what he was not. (I was thinking of "turn skin" or "werewolf", but I'm not sure whether they would work in the context.)

Comment: **They give the superficial impression that ...**  or if we **know** that the good impression is false **All hat and no cattle**

Comment: @djna - Thanks, I also found "all frosting, no cupcake", "all show, no go", etc.

Comment: I think the phrase *from top to toe* doesn't suggest anything about being or not being able to get the right idea, or even an impression at first sight.

Comment: At first I thought he was a gentleman [through and through](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/through_and_through), but later I found out he was a [wolf in sheep's clothing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wolf_in_sheep%27s_clothing).  I don't think that "wolf lin sheep's clothing" is quite right. It has a more specific meaning than just "not what he appeared to be", but it is something you might hear in a similar context.

Comment: @DamkerngT. - What phrase may it be then? "To one's fingertips" or "through and through"? I'm asking for that too.

Comment: I'll admit that I'm not quite sure about the real intended question in this question! *From head/tip/top to heels/toe*, *through and through*, *to one's fingertips* share more or less the same idea, which has nothing to do with finding out later that they're *all hat, no cattle* or *wolf in sheep's clothing* or *all talk*, which is yet different from the suggested warnings like *don't judge a book by its cover* or *looks can be deceiving*.

Comment: @ColleenV - Thanks a lot. I was thinking of "turn skin" or "werewolf". Would you mind letting me know if you'd have a better suggestion? An answer from you would be great!

Comment: I think @DamkerngT. has a point that there is really more than one question here. "Someone who seems to be one thing but isn't" is different from "the idea that you can't know what something is like by one glance" is different from "a way to describe someone who is in all ways a certain way". They're all related, but the answer is different for each thing. I don't know whether it makes sense to break these into separate questions when they're closely related, but you may want to edit your question to make clear the three different things you're asking for.

Comment: @DamkerngT. - "He's a military man through and through" is the example [from here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/through+and+through)/ Again: I am also asking for a phrase to express the idea of being **entirely** a certain type of a person.

Comment: @Rompey What I tried to point out in my first comment was that in, say, *He's a military man through and through*, the idiom has nothing to do with his really being a military man or just looking like a military man. Judging from your last comment, maybe you misunderstand the idiom. Of course, it could be use in the context you may be thinking of, but it doesn't always carry that connotation.

Comment: I can't off the top of my head think of a phrase that implies that work very hard to give an impression of being one thing while being another.  One that may work is _in name only_.  If he is "a gentleman in name only" then he is not a gentleman, even though he calls himself one.  _Self-styled_ may work for that as well.

Comment: Just so I understand better - is Mr. X purposefully misleading Ms. Z to make her believe he is a gentleman even though he is far from it, or is Ms. Z just not a very good judge of character? Is the fault for the wrong impression with Ms. Z or with Mr. X?

Comment: @ColleenV - It's sooner Mr.X's appearance and style of behavior that made Mrs.Z take him for what he is not. There may also be a lack of information about some of his traits,  habits or secret predilections that  he doesn't want anyone to know  or even guess about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an old saying:

> Don't judge a book by it's cover.

meaning that outward appearances can be deceiving, there is also the literal

> Looks can be deceiving.

This was used to good effect in an ad campaign by Sunkist oranges using the tag line

> [If it doesn't say Sunkist, you don't know what you're getting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jP09HFiRD0)

Such idioms exist throughout different cultures and languages.

To say that someone is fully of a certain type, one might say

> That person is 100% *something*
>   *That person is 100% a gentleman*
>
> That person is totally *something*
>   *That person is totally lost*
>
> That person is completely *something*
>   *That person is completely Swedish*

Comment: Thanks a lot, and I also found "Beauty is only skin deep".

Comment: That's another one, though specific to gender. There is also "His bark is worse than his bite", meaning *someone* who appears to be rough and combative but is not so dangerous.

Comment: I disagree that "beauty is only skin deep" is gender-specific.

Comment: it's its not it's

Answer (score 1):

*He is ever the gentleman.* (UK usage.)

*Isn't he ever the gentleman.* (...with a touch of irony.)

*He is quite the gentleman, isn't he?*

*He is such a gentleman.* (Informal.)

*He is gentleman in full.* (Slightly archaic.)

*He is a perfect example of a gentleman.*

*He is the very model of a gentleman.* (Only jocularly nowadays, because of a famous song.)

*He is the very picture of a gentleman.* (This emphasises appearances and thus first impressions.)

*He is a gentleman in every way / in all respects.*

*He does rather strike one as a gentleman.* (Again, only jocularly.)

*He cuts a dashing figure.*